# Trying to make a program that handles SIGUSR1, the Child should exec another executable

Tags: c, makefile, fork, exec

As the title says I am trying to make a program that handles SIGUSR1, the Child of the program needs to exec another executable. This can either be hard coded or come from the command line, I chose to hard code for now.

This is being coded in C from vim (got to love Linux class).

My parent seems to function at least the printf() are running at the end.

I have two .c files one called parent.c the other called child.c

The code for my parent program is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int signalHandle(int signo)
{
        if(signo == SIGUSR1)
        {
                printf("Signal recived from child.\n");
        }
        else
                printf("Unexpected signal received");
        return;

}


int main()
{
        pid_t child = fork();
        if (child == 0)
        {
                execvp("child", signalHandle(child));
        }

        sleep(10);
        printf("Now finishing the parent process pid of %d\n", getpid());


}
```

The Child program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                         
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                        


int main()                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                          

        printf("This is the child, with pid %d and parent pid %d\nHello World", getpid(), getppid());      
        sleep(5);                                                                                          
        printf("Now exiting the child program...\n");                                                      
        return 0;                                                                                          

}
```

I have a makefile that looks like:

```
all: parent child                        

parent: parent.c                         
        gcc -o parent parent.c           

child: child.c                           
        gcc -o child child.c
```

When I run the Makefile I get some warnings:

```
gcc -o parent parent.c
parent.c: In function ‘signalHandle’:
parent.c:14:2: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void
  return;
  ^
parent.c: In function ‘main’:
parent.c:21:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fork’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  pid_t child = fork();
                ^
parent.c:24:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execvp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   execvp("child", signalHandle(child));
   ^
parent.c:27:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sleep’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  sleep(10);
  ^
parent.c:28:57: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getpid’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("Now finishing the parent process pid of %d\n", getpid());
                                                         ^
gcc -o child child.c
child.c: In function ‘main’:
child.c:8:74: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getpid’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("This is the child, with pid %d and parent pid %d\nHello World", getpid(), getppid());
                                                                          ^
child.c:8:84: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getppid’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("This is the child, with pid %d and parent pid %d\nHello World", getpid(), getppid());
                                                                                    ^
child.c:9:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sleep’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  sleep(5);
  ^
```

It does run but the current output of my program is:

```
zerkereod@zerkereod-VirtualBox:~/Class/admin/asullivan/lab7$ ./parent
Now finishing the parent process pid of 9763
zerkereod@zerkereod-VirtualBox:~/Class/admin/asullivan/lab7$ Unexpected signal receivedNow finishing the parent process pid of 9764
```

I have looked up a good amount of code but everyone I see using exec use argv or argv[] and no one explains why. And I do not know what the signal handler is for. Extended expressions and signals are killing me for this class. And no matter how much I read I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `execvp` call, but that's not how it works. [Read an `execvp` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html). Find some tutorials. You should probably [read a `fork` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

`parent.c:14:2: warning:` this is because `int signalHandle(int signo);`
 should return an *int* and when you type `return;` you are trying to return nothing. You should change the prototype for `void signalHandle(int signo);`, since this function doesn't return a value.

`fork()`is a function from `unistd.h`. Since your are not including this lib, the compiler doesn't recognize it. Idem for the ‘execvp’, 'sleep', 'getpid' and 'getppid'. You should add

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

to your code, so you can use these functions.

To declare signal handlers, you must include `signal.h` lib. To declare a function as a signal handler, you have to use `signal` function for this. A handler should receive only one argument (the signal) and return void.

The correct way to your parent process to capture a SIGUSR1 signal is:

```
void signalHandle(int signo)
{
    printf("Signal SIGUSR1 received from child.\n");
}
```

In parent.c main you have to call:

```
signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandle);
```

To make the child process send a signal do the parent process you have to use 'kill' function:

```
kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
```

And you are passing the wrong arguments to execvp. First argument should be the name of .exe file. The second argument is a string array, where the first element should also be the name of the file and the last one must be NULL:

```
char *argv[2];
argv[0] = "child";
argv[1] = NULL;
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

You should learn a bit more in these links:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html